# Using Eigen Library for fixed-point matrix multiplication

Tags: eigen, matrix-multiplication, fixed-point

Does [Eigen Library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) have support for fixed-point multiplication? Currently, I perform matrix multiplication without Eigen Library and use the following fixed-point multiplication function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31662911/4921865

The best I can think of is converting my numbers into double the precision and then using Eigen Library. Any ideas on this would be appreciated!

Comment: You can use a custom type inside Eigen matrices by following these instructions: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_CustomScalar.html

Comment: I will give it a try, thank you!