# the efficient way to get the high 32 bits of the product of two unsigned integers c++

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

```
unsigned int a = 4294967295;  // (2^32)-1
unsigned int b = 2;
```

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to get the high 32 bits of the product of two unsigned integers.
For example, using CUDA programming I can just `unsigned int first32bits = __umulhi(a,b)` and get the high 32 bits.

Are there ways to do such thing in C++?

Here's my approach:

```
unsigned long c = ( ((unsigned long)a * (unsigned long)b ) >> 32) & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF;
```

Are there any ways to make my approach faster?

Comment: I don't think standard C++ gives you the tools to do this efficiently. You need to look at proprietary methods such as the one you discovered for CUDA.

Comment: "most efficient" .. and doesn't provide any information about platform.  Write correct code, then profile it if it's not fast enough to see where the actual bottlenecks are.

Comment: @xaxxon I've included my code.

Comment: Off topic: [Take a look at fixed with integers.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) They will protect you somewhat from nasty surprises like an implementation with a 16 bit `int`. It'll still be a nasty surprise, but the code won't compile if the fixed  `int` is unavailable so you get an early heads-up.

Comment: You may get away with `(uint64_t(a)*b)>>32`, I remember seeing at least gcc recognizing this pattern and perform a normal `mul`and keeping the high part straight from `edx`.

Comment: If there is no equivalent of umulhi() on your platform, you may need to write some assembly code. It is possible that an optimizing compiler would generate optimal code equivalent to umulhi().

Comment: @Mint.K The "most efficient" way depends massively on the underlying architecture.  Posting your code doesn't make your question more answerable.  For instance, if your int is 32 bits, then you already have the high 32 bits.  And the low 32 bits.  But you haven't told us anything about what platform you're on.

Comment: The solution is not portable because unsigned long may be 32 bit.

Comment: You need `unsigned long` to be at least 64 bits for your approach to work, but that's not guaranteed.  It would also be nice to save that last mask.  I'd switch to C++11 and try `unsigned long long c = (((unsigned long long)a * (unsigned long long)b) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFU) >> 32` with the hope that the compiler will drop the mask if `unsigned long long` is exactly 64 bits.  (I'm assuming that `unsigned int` is exactly 32 bits.)

Comment: Your initialisation of `a` assumes `unsigned int` is (at least) 32 bit - it is actually able to be 16 bit.   Similarly, your approach assumes `unsigned long` is 64-bit or more, while it can actually be only 32 bit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient computation of the high order bits of a 32 bit integer multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396942/efficient-computation-of-the-high-order-bits-of-a-32-bit-integer-multiplication)

Answer (score 2):

Unless there is some architecture dependent circuitry that maps `imulh32` to a native instruction then I think that that is sort of the best you can do.

Looking at the assembly generated by `g++ 6.3` for your function, it is clear than it costs just `1` assembly operation more than a function which only does multiplication because of the `shr $0x20`.

```
 unsigned long umulhi32( unsigned int x,  unsigned int y)
{
  return ( ((unsigned long)a * (unsigned long)b ) >> 32);
}
0000000000000960 <_Z8umulhi32jy>:
 960:   89 f8                   mov    %edi,%eax
 962:   89 f7                   mov    %esi,%edi
 964:   48 0f af c7             imul   %rdi,%rax
 968:   48 c1 e8 20             shr    $0x20,%rax
 96c:   c3                      retq   
 96d:   0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)
```

It would be interesting to have the assembly of the `cuda umulhi` in order to see if it maps to some dedicated PTX instruction which I think is very likely to be so since the `PTX` assembly used by `cuda` exposes, for instance, the `mul24` which ([quoting](http://www.nvidia.com/content/cuda-ptx_isa_1.4.pdf))

> mul24.hi performs a 24x24-bit multiply and returns the high 32 bits of
>   the 48-bit result

As far as I know, there are not such instructions in x86 assembly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: there's no such instruction in x86 because single-operand `mul` and `imul` always produce the full results. However SSE/AVX typically have non-widening multiplication so there are such instructions like PMULHUW, PMULHW, PMULHRSW, [VPMULHW](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/523894)... to get the high bits of the result

Comment: I'm not really a low level guy! So that is definitely an interesting add. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Intrinsics like __umulhi() are designed to use fewer / specialized instructions on specific architectures (Nvidia GPUs here). You would have to look at proprietary solutions as suggested in the comments (e.g. [Intel](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/a6/22/18072-347603.pdf) for CPU) rather than expect something from C++.

In this situation I highly doubt you will find an intrinsic that replaces your approach with any meaningful performance increases.